# PHP API Content-Type: application/json. Response empty data

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, api

Works fine for:

- Sending from Android platform to PHP (web service)
- Request headers sent with this `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Not working for:

- Request headers sent with `Content-Type: application/json`. no data is received

API is working on same platform but not in cross platform:

- Web to web WORKING
- Android to web NOT WORKING

In PHP added both header on top:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after log search i found my answer..
we need this function to get $_POST response from cross platform (android to web)

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

OR we can also use this function to get $_POST response

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

here is complete function to get the response.

```
$data = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compare these two content types application/x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json in a "The first works with PHP, the second doesn't", then you probably expect the data to appear magically inside $_POST in both cases.

This will not happen. PHP only fills $_POST if the first content type is given (alternatively, application/multipart-form-data can be used for everything, especially file uploads).

If you want to use application/json, then you have to implement a parser on the PHP side yourself that reads the HTTP request body and parses it to your liking.